# PHP group by date and ID

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Let's assume I have this array

```
 [
    {
                    "id": "1_8u48bxhw",
                    "patterns": [
                        "22/04/2021 08:40:54",
                        "22/04/2021 08:43:23"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "1_1ds3ygvn",
                    "patterns": [
                        "22/04/2021 08:37:45",
                        "23/04/2021 08:53:38",
                        "26/04/2021 02:30:42",
                        "26/04/2021 02:31:22",
                        "26/04/2021 02:32:02"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "1_5z9ywdxv",
                    "patterns": [
                        "22/04/2021 08:36:43",
                        "23/04/2021 08:52:18",
                        "23/04/2021 08:53:00",
                        "23/04/2021 08:53:45",
                        "23/04/2021 08:54:04",
                        "23/04/2021 08:57:23",
                        "23/04/2021 08:57:23",
                        "23/04/2021 08:58:31"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "1_uwiyjoda",
                    "patterns": [
                        "22/04/2021 08:41:02",
                        "22/04/2021 08:41:10"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "1_zs32zdjr",
                    "patterns": [
                        "22/04/2021 08:42:38",
                        "22/04/2021 08:42:44"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "1_pr1hvl3x",
                    "patterns": [
                        "22/04/2021 08:36:58",
                        "22/04/2021 08:38:04",
                        "22/04/2021 08:38:20",
                        "22/04/2021 08:42:11"
                    ]
                }
 ]
```

I tried to group the date with ID.

And my expected result should be:

```
[ {
    "id": "1_8u48bxhw",
    "dates": {
        "22/04/2021": [
          "22/04/2021 08:40:54",
          "22/04/2021 08:43:23"
        ]
     }
   },
   {
     "id": "1_1ds3ygvn",
     "dates": {
           "22/04/2021": [
               "22/04/2021 08:37:45"
            ],
            "23/04/2021": [
                "23/04/2021 08:53:38"
            ],
            "26/04/2021": [
                 "26/04/2021 02:30:42",
                 "26/04/2021 02:31:22",
                 "26/04/2021 02:32:02"
            ]
      }
    },
    // and so on...
 ]
```

This is the code that I have tried

```
    $groupDate = array();
    $groupByDate = [];
    $watchPatterns = [];
    foreach ($watchDatetime as $watchTime) {
        $id = $watchTime['id'];
        $patterns = $watchTime['patterns'];
        $dateGrouped = null;
        if ($patterns) {
            foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
                $dateSplit = explode(" ", $pattern);
                $date = $dateSplit[0];
                $groupDate[$date][] = $pattern;
            }
        }
        array_push($groupByDate, [
            'id' => $id,
            'dates' => $groupDate
        ]);
    }
    array_push($watchPatterns, $groupByDate);
```

But the result does not come like what I expected.
Below is the actual result:

```
{
                    "id": "1_8u48bxhw",
                    "dates": {
                        "22/04/2021": [
                            "22/04/2021 08:40:54",
                            "22/04/2021 08:43:23"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "1_1ds3ygvn",
                    "dates": {
                        "22/04/2021": [
                            // duplicate from first
                            "22/04/2021 08:40:54",
                            "22/04/2021 08:43:23",
                             //
                            "22/04/2021 08:37:45"
                        ],
                        "23/04/2021": [
                            "23/04/2021 08:53:38"
                        ],
                        "26/04/2021": [
                            "26/04/2021 02:30:42",
                            "26/04/2021 02:31:22",
                            "26/04/2021 02:32:02"
                        ]
                    }
                },
```

If you notice the second array keeps duplicating the date from the first array and so on for the rest of the array.

Comment: You need to reset $groupDate each iteration to an empty array, instead of just the 1 init at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Mr Tobias K. said. You need to reset the array for each iteration

```
$groupDate = array();
    $groupByDate = [];
    foreach ($watchDatetime as $watchTime) {
        $id = $watchTime['id'];
        $patterns = $watchTime['patterns'];
        $dateGrouped = null;
        if ($patterns) {
            // new line
            $groupDate = null;
            foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
                $dateSplit = explode(" ", $pattern);
                $date = $dateSplit[0];
                $groupDate[$date][] = $pattern;
            }

        }
        array_push($groupByDate, [
            'id' => $id,
            'dates' => $groupDate
        ]);
    }
    array_push($watchPatterns, $groupByDate);
```